# Reading File Records and Assigning to an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm creating a poker stats WinForm program to write player info and 8 weeks' worth of winnnings and a total winnings amount to a file and read that info to display in a form.  I'm having issues reading the 8 weekly winnings amounts textboxes into my array.  I receive an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.  I've noted in the code below where I think the error is coming from.  I've included both the form code and my class code.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I hope I've provided enough background of the issue.  Thanks in advance!!

My form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PokerStats
{
    public partial class FormPokerStats : Form  // FormPokerStats inheriting from class Form
    {
        // declaring and assigning of variables needed for file read/write
        const char DELIM = ',';
        const string FILEPATH = @"C:\C# Project Output\";
        const string FILENAME = "PokerPlayers.txt";

        // declaring instances of Person, Location, and Winnings classes
        Person myplayer = new Person();
        Location mycasino = new Location();
        Winnings mywinnings = new Winnings();

        // constructing in/out FileStream/StreamReader/StreamWriter objects
        static FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILEPATH + FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
        static FileStream outFile = new FileStream(FILEPATH + FILENAME, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);

        public FormPokerStats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // "Enter/Update Player" tab Enter Player button: read/assign user input, write to file, close file stream 
        private void buttonEnterPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if directory does not exist, create it
            if (!(Directory.Exists(FILEPATH)))
            {
                // create directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FILEPATH);
            }

            try
            {
                // read user input and assign to variables; test for empty player inputs and reprompt for input, if necessary
                // Player Information fields
                // if any or all textboxes are left blank
                if ((textBoxSSN.Text == String.Empty || textBoxFirstName.Text == String.Empty || textBoxLastName.Text == String.Empty
                    || textBoxCasinoName.Text == String.Empty || textBoxCasinoState.Text == String.Empty) ||
                    (textBoxSSN.Text == String.Empty && textBoxFirstName.Text == String.Empty && textBoxLastName.Text == String.Empty
                    && textBoxCasinoName.Text == String.Empty && textBoxCasinoState.Text == String.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please complete all player information fields.", "Input Error!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // if all textboxes are completed, assign to variables
                    myplayer.SocialSecurityNumber = textBoxSSN.Text;
                    myplayer.FirstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
                    myplayer.LastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
                    mycasino.CasinoName = textBoxCasinoName.Text;
                    mycasino.CasinoState = textBoxCasinoState.Text;

                    // writing record to text file
                    writer.WriteLine(myplayer.ToString() + mycasino.ToString());

                    // if record is successfully written, display messagebox
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrote " + myplayer.FirstName.ToString() + ' ' + myplayer.LastName.ToString() + " to file with winnings totaling " + mywinnings.TotalWinnings.ToString("C2") + ".", "File Written");
                }
***************************ERROR HERE***************************
                // read weekly winnings input and assign to appropriate array position; test for empty inputs and assign default value of 0 if empty
                // Week1
                if (textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 0);

                //// Week2
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 1);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text, 1);

                //// Week3
                //if (textBoxWeek3Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 2);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek3Winnings.Text, 2);

                //// Week4
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 3);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 3);

                //// Week5
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 4);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 4);

                //// Week6
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 5);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 5);

                //// Week7
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 6);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 6);

                //// Week8
                //if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                //{
                //    mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray("0", 7);
                //}
                //else mywinnings.ReadWinningsIntoArray(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text, 7);

                //// calculate total winnings by summing WeeklyWinnings array values and assigning to TotalWinnings
                //mywinnings.TotalWinnings = mywinnings.WeeklyWinnings.Sum();
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // if format exception is thrown in try, display messagebox with message
                MessageBox.Show("Winnings must be entered at xx.xx (e.g. 34.56).", "Input Error!");
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                // if exception is thrown in try, display messagebox with message
                MessageBox.Show(f.Message, "Error!");
            }

            // clear form textboxes
            ClearTextBoxes();
            writer.Close();
        }

        // "Enter/Update Player" tab Exit button: closes file streams and quits the application
        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // closing file streams
            reader.Close();
            inFile.Close();
            writer.Close();
            outFile.Close();

            // close application
            Application.Exit();
        }

        // "Player List" tab View Player Winnings button: read file records, display records sorted by total winnings descending
        private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            // if file exists
            if (!(File.Exists(FILEPATH + FILENAME)))
            {
                // if file does not exist, display messagebox
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist.", "File Does Not Exist!");
            }
            else
            {
                string[] fields;

                // read first record in file
                string recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

                listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Add("First Name\tLast Name\tCasino Name\tCasino State\tTotal Winnings\t");

                while (recordIn != null)
                {
                    // split record into array and assign
                    fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                    myplayer.SocialSecurityNumber = fields[0];
                    myplayer.FirstName = fields[1];
                    myplayer.LastName = fields[2];
                    mycasino.CasinoName = fields[3];
                    mycasino.CasinoState = fields[4];

                    // output record to listbox
                    listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Add(myplayer.FirstName + "\t\t" + myplayer.LastName + "\t\t" + mycasino.CasinoName + "\t\t" + mycasino.CasinoState + "\t\t");

                    // read next record in file
                    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
            }

            // return file position to 0
            inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        // "Player List" tab Exit button: call buttonExit_Click method
        private void buttonExit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call buttonExit_Click method
            buttonExit_Click(sender, e);
        }

        // method to clear listbox items when "Player List" tab is left
        private void tabPagePlayerList_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clear listbox items
            listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Clear();
        }

        // method to clear textbox controls
        private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).Clear();
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

My class code:

```
class Person
{
    // SocialSecurityNumber, FirstName, LastName properties
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // overridden ToString() method to return string output
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (SocialSecurityNumber + ',' + FirstName + ',' + LastName + ',');
    }
}

// Location class
class Location
{
    // CasinoName and CasinoState properties
    public string CasinoName { get; set; }
    public string CasinoState { get; set; }

    // overridden ToString() method to return string output
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (CasinoName + ',' + CasinoState + ',');
    }
}

// Winnings class
class Winnings
{
    double[] weeklyWinnings = new double[8];

    // WeeklyWinnings and TotalWinnings properties
    public double[] WeeklyWinnings { get; set; }
    public double TotalWinnings { get; set; }

    // overridden ToString() method to return string output
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (  WeeklyWinnings[0].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[1].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[2].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[3].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[4].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[5].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[6].ToString("C2") + ','
                + WeeklyWinnings[7].ToString("C2") + ','
                + TotalWinnings.ToString("C2"));
    }

    // method to read textbox winnings inputs into the array
    public void ReadWinningsIntoArray(string textBoxText, int position)
    {
        double value;
        if (double.TryParse(textBoxText, out value))
            WeeklyWinnings[position] = Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `textBoxWeek1Winnings` properly defined in a designer file?  If not, the null is because this variable isn't defined anywhere and that is the problem.

---

I would think in the design view of the form you should be able to see the name of the textboxes for the winnings and this is what you haven't set correctly.  In declaring a new textbox

[Dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox) has an example that may be useful to consider for how you are coding this as I think you're missing something relatively simple here.

Comment: I'm having issues with formatting the comment, but I believe it's being properly defined: 

'this.textBoxWeek1Winnings = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();' 

'this.tabPagePlayer.Controls.Add(this.textBoxWeek1Winnings);' 

'private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxWeek1Winnings;'

Comment: I just copy and pasted certain lines of the code from the Designer file.  I haven't modified that file at all.  I've let Visual Studio handle all that for me.  So I'm confused as to how the issue could exist in that file?

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code by making use of the [`File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) methods.

Comment: Certain requirements have to be met for this.  Otherwise, I'd surely utilize those methods.  I found them when I first started working on this.  Thanks for the tip though!